# What's this product of groups?

Tags: group-theory, products, direct-product

Let $G=\Bbb Z[\frac12]/\Bbb Z$ be the (additive) Prufer 2-group and let $\Bbb Z$ be the group of integers.

Let $X=G\times \Bbb Z$ be the following product:

---

Let $g_n$ be the subgroups of $G$ in increasing order.

So $g_0$ is the smallest (the trivial) subgroup of $G$ and let $g_n$ be defined recursively so $g_n=\left\{x\in G,\nu_2(x)\geq-n,\right\}$

Then $X=\bigcup_n\left(g_n \times \Bbb Z^n\right)$

---

> Is there a name for this form of product $G\times \Bbb Z$?
>
> Is there a name for this group $X$?

It's isomorphic to the ordinal $\omega^\omega$ adjusted by a map which sends the coefficients of every term in Cantor normal form from $\Bbb N\to\Bbb Z$, with the elements of $G$ serving to indicate whether any given coefficient is positive or negative.

Comment: I've never seen that before, but I would be happy to call it a (filtered) blow-up of $G$.

Comment: Thanks @ArnaudMortier I guess you're using this: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filtration_(mathematics) and this: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blowing_up

Comment: To be honest I don't have any reference, it just seems (to me) to be an appropriate terminology in case it's new. Oh I see you're pointing at two separate references. Well, yes, "blowing up" in some cases denotes replacing each piece of a space by its product with something elementary (such as a contractible space in topology), and then glue everything back together in a natural way.